# How to get Foursquare Autocomplete response that are filtered through specified categories?

Tags: android, foursquare

Is it possible to use [Get Autocomplete Results](https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/autocomplete-1) with [categories](https://location.foursquare.com/places/docs/categories) to filter the response and return addresses, places(filtered with specified categories), geos, and/or searches?

I want to avoid filtering my response inside the app.

Answer (score 1):

Hello this feature is not available yet. I will submit a feature request to inform the engineering team and understand the feasibility.

Thanks for your question! You can also join our Discord for more direct support.

https://discord.gg/foursquaredevs

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available on the [Place Search (`/v3/places/search`)](https://location.foursquare.com/developer/reference/place-search) endpoint, which has a `categories` parameter, which can accept a list of [Category IDs](https://location.foursquare.com/places/docs/categories).

> `categories: string`
> Filters the response and returns FSQ Places matching the specified categories. Supports multiple Category IDs, separated by commas.